# ProgressDialog on UI thread takes too long to appear

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have the following in my main activity:

```
private void attemptLogin() {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(cntxt, "", "Loading...", true);
        }
    });
    // continue...
}
```

However the dialog does not appear, either on a device or the simulator, for a long time, until after my login process is complete (by which time it gets dismissed anyway).

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It seems you are calling this method after your big process. Can you post your code(more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let you know how runOnUIThread() works is that,

It starts when your activity is finished with the default UIThread it has, and then the runOnUIThread() will be called. so if you have running something in your activity, this will not appear.

I would suggest you to use AsyncTasks.. since you haven't posted any code, all my suggestions are based on the assumption that you are running something in your activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use async task like this:

```
private class BackgroundLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void , InputStream>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG); //SHOW PROGRESS DIALOG                 
    }
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        //Take Data from server or 
        //whatever your background work while progress dialog is spinning
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream responseStream)
    {
          removeDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG); //REMOVE IT (dont cancel it)
    }
```

You can add/show progress dialog by creating like this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle("");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true); //Imp line
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            return dialog;
```